# How do I check user input from a file in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

Let's say I have a text file:

```
Alice,Bob,Charles,David,Emily,Frank
```

I want to check if a string that the user enters matches a name in the text file, something like this:

```
Name = str(input("Enter a name here: ")

if Name == Alice:
    print("Foo")
elif Name == Bob:
    print("Bar")
```

How do I do it?

Comment: Which part are you struggling with? Do you know how to read a file?

Comment: Do you require the name of the text file to match or do you mean to say that you have some content in the file and you need to find, if the words Alice and Bob are present in that file? Please Elaborate!

Answer (score 0):

1. Assuming that you want to check if a string that the user enters matches a name **in the text file** then you should read your text file in advance and then compare to the user input as follows

   > ```
   > names = [i.split(',') for i in open('names.txt', 'r')][0]
   > Name = input()
   > [name+' is in the list' for name in names if name == Name]
   > ```
2. Assuming that you want to check if a string that the user enters matches a name **in the name of a text file** then you should read your text file names in advance and then compare to the user input as follows:

   > ```
   > names = os.listdir(directory)
   > Name = input()
   > [name+' is in the list' for name in names if name == Name]
   > ```

Comment: Please don't use list comprehensions to run a loop that merely prints. List comprehensions are intended to produce a value (the list), whereas print is intended to trigger a side-effect (the output) and produce no value.

Answer (score -2):

lets assume that your directory looks something like this :

```
$cd folder
$ls 
Alice  Bob  Charles  David  Emily  Frank
```

Then you can do it by.

```
Name = str(input("Enter a name here: ")
if Name in os.listdir('folder'):
    print("Name found!!!!  {}".format(Name))
```